# Python 2.6 and unicode

Tags: python, browser, unicode, encoding, pyqt

So I am working for a web browser type of application for my client and I just implemented bookmarking functionality, but it doesn't work as expected. When user click "Bookmark page" a little form pops up, which takes title of a webpage and puts it in a line edit. The thing is, that if the website has some foreign or unusual symbols in it's title then Python throws an error how it can't encode the string. How could I get python to handle all possible strings, no matter if it has hieroglyphs or some other weird symbols?

Library used for GUI and embedded browser: PyQT

Comment: Without the code it's difficult to guess, especially since your title already shows you know the solution is using unicode...

Comment: I tried unicode(web.title(), "utf-8"), but then got an error that I can't store bytecode in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `QWebView.title` to get the title of the current web-page, then it will either return a `QString` or a python unicode string. Which one you get depends on the PyQt API version in use. For version 1 (which is the default for Python2), it will be a `QString`; for version 2 (which is the default for Python3), it will be a python unicode string. Whichever it is, in order to display it correctly in the line-edit, just set it directly:

```
lineEdit.setText(webview.title())
```

Since you appear to be using Python2, I'll assume that `webview.title()` is returning a `QString`. If you want to convert this to a python unicode string (e.g. in order to use it with sqlite), then you can do the following:

```
title = unicode(webview.title())
```

Note that you should *not* pass an encoding (such as "utf-8") as the second argument to `unicode`, as this is used for *decoding* byte strings to unicode strings.

If you *do* need to get a "utf-8" encoded byte string from a `QString`, then you can either do:

```
data = unicode(webview.title()).encode('utf-8')
```

or:

```
data = webview.title().toUtf8().data()
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to parse the websites? I would recommend [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). It will try and determine the encoding of the web page and give you back unicode. [Beautiful Soup's Parsing HTML section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20HTML). Edit: Also take a look at the "Beautiful Soup Gives You Unicode, Dammit" section

Comment: I am using QWebView from PyQT to display website and get needed data from it.

Comment: Ok, I can't help any further I'm afraid as I have zero experience with PyQT. You could use this as a last resort and fetch the page separately if you cannot find a way to do this using QWebView, but @ekhumoro's solution seems far more appropriate here